# Get Twitter's profiles using Java

Tags: java, twitter, profile, twitter4j

I'm doing an app which using Java with Twitter4j, I want to access to other Twitter user's profile information (id,name, etc) but these users are not followers or friends of mine. Now I only can access of my follower's and friend's profiles. Here is my code (to access to my followers):

```
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
          cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");


    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());

    twitter = tf.getInstance();
    long cursor = -1;

    do {
                if (0 < args.length) {
                    ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(args[0], cursor);
                } else {
                    ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(cursor);
                }
     } while ((cursor = ids.getNextCursor()) != 0);
```

Also, Twitter gives an URL to access to this data with get_user (OAuth Signature Generator) but if I put it into a browser, it doesn't work (anyway, I don't have a clue about use it):

```
Request URI: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json 
Request query: q=Twitter%20API&amp;page=1&amp;count=3
Final URL: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=Twitter%20API&page=1&count=3
```

Exist a way to access to these data?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view an individual by using [`showUser`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UsersResources.html#showUser(long)), by screen-name or id, e.g.:

```
User user = twitter.showUser(id);

User user = twitter.showUser(screenName);
```

But if you need to retrieve multiple users, it's better to use [`lookupUsers`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UsersResources.html#lookupUsers(long[])) instead, e.g.:

```
long[] ids = ...
ResponseList<User> users = twitter.lookupUsers(ids);

String[] screenNames = ...
ResponseList<User> users = twitter.lookupUsers(screenNames);
```

Twitter4J has [some of the examples](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/tree/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples) that you might find useful.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan for your time. But, how do you get that id? For example, if I want to access to your profile (you and I aren't followers or friends in Twitter). I need to know your ID if I want to use the showUser function with you.

Comment: You need to either know an id or a screen-name. If you don't know either, you could try searching users - take a look a [this example](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/user/SearchUsers.java#L42) for more information.

Comment: Thank you again Jonathan in your example I saw a search function. I will try to do a query and search for that query and recover the associated tweets. If I have the tweets I can be able to discover the users.

Comment: Yes, if you have tweets, e.g. a `Status` in Twitter4J, you should be able to do `status.getUser()`. In that case you wouldn't need to show or lookup users.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and instructions. You just made my day :)